# Tree Traversal - how sort results?

Tags: php, sorting, structure

I have simple table form which I'm gettting data hierarchically using Tree traversal.

It works nice, but now I need to add a new function. I need to sort data **in each level** by value saved for each row in new column in databes [rank].

My table is:

```
+----+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------+------+
| ID | LFT | RGT | DEPTH | PARENT |   NAME     | RANK |
+----+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------+------+
|  1 |   1 |  22 |     0 |      0 | Category   |   10 |
|  2 |   2 |  15 |     1 |      1 | Fruit      |    8 |
|  3 |   3 |   8 |     2 |      2 | Apples     |    8 |
|  4 |   4 |   5 |     3 |      3 | Red        |    5 |
|  5 |   6 |   7 |     3 |      3 | Green      |    5 |
|  6 |   9 |  14 |     2 |      2 | Bannana    |    9 |
|  7 |  10 |  11 |     3 |      6 | Long       |    1 |
|  8 |  12 |  13 |     3 |      6 | Short      |    2 |
|  9 |  16 |  21 |     1 |      0 | Vegetables |    9 |
| 10 |  17 |  18 |     2 |      9 | Carrots    |    5 |
| 11 |  19 |  20 |     2 |      9 | Potatoes   |    6 |
| 12 |   8 |   9 |     3 |      3 | Yellow     |   10 |
+----+-----+-----+-------+--------+------------+------+
```

For list the structure I'm using following script:

```
$lftrgt  = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("SELECT name,lft,rgt,rank FROM myTable WHERE id='$id'"));
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE rgt < $lftrgt[rgt] AND lft > $lftrgt[lft] ORDER BY lft");
if(!$result) { echo mysql_error() . ' - ' . mysql_errno(); }
$depth = -1;
echo "<b><u>".$lftrgt[name] ." (rank: ". $lftrgt[rank] .")</u></b>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
if ($depth < $row["depth"]) {
echo "<ul>";
} else {
echo str_repeat("</li></ul>", $depth - $row["depth"]) . "</li>";
}
echo "<li>\n" . htmlspecialchars($row["name"]) ." (rank: " . $row[rank] . ")";
$depth = $row["depth"];
}
echo str_repeat("</li></ul>", $depth + 1) . "\n";
mysql_free_result($result);
```

For better idea, there is picture what I need:

[image: screenshot]

How to sort results in each level in descending order? Thanks.

Comment: You could read your data into an array and use http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php to sort it.

Comment: As a first step, you should put the data into a data structure, which you then can operate on.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.